# How to filter events alone for PersistentVolumeClaim yaml file?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

We have created pvc and they are in pending state. So in order to check the state we execute

```
Kubectl describe -f <pvc.yml>
```

it displays result as below

```
Name:          myproj-pvc-2020-09-29-04-02-1601377369-49419-1
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  myproj-storageclass-2020-09-29-04-02-1601377366
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        ansible=csitest-2020-09-29-04-02-1601377369-49419-1
               pvcRef=csi-pvc-ansibles-1
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: csi.myorg.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                  From                                                                                   Message
  ----     ------                ----                 ----                                                                                   -------
  Normal   Provisioning          85s (x8 over 4m43s)  csi.myorg.com_csicentos76w3.mylab.myprojstorage.com_2e1a7c1d-7542-42a5-a2e1-491e1d04b4ee  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/myproj-pvc-2020-09-29-04-02-1601377369-49419-1"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    74s (x8 over 4m33s)  csi.myorg.com_csicentos76w3.mylab.myprojstorage.com_2e1a7c1d-7542-42a5-a2e1-491e1d04b4ee  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "myproj-storageclass-2020-09-29-04-02-1601377366": rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = Failed to get storage provider from secrets, Request failed with status code 401 and errors Error code (Unauthorized) and message (HTTP 401 Unauthorized.)
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  6s (x20 over 4m43s)  persistentvolume-controller                                                            waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "csi.myorg.com" or manually created by system administrat
```

What I need is to filter only events of this pvc.yaml?  If i execute `kubectl get -f pvc.yaml -o json` it doesn't display error events in json

I can do `kubectl describe -f <pvc.yml> | grep -A10 Events:`  but there is no guarantee that only 10 lines will be always error.

Also i found this way `kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind="PersistentVolumeClaim"` but this will show all events related to all pvc. I need to get events of Pvc list mentioned in pvc.yml file.

How to filter events of all pvc in pvc.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl get -f pvc.yaml -o json` does work, but I assume you meant `kubectl get events -f pvc.yaml -o json`

kubectl doesn't seem to allow for such filtering. You may want to open a feature request on [kubectl github issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues).

But meanwhile, here is what I came up with as an alternative:

```
kubectl get -f <pvc.yml> -ojson \
 | jq ".items[] | .metadata.name" \
 | xargs -I{} kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind="PersistentVolumeClaim",involvedObject.name={} --no-headers --ignore-not-found
```

Notce that you need `jq` installed. You could also use `yq` and you wouldn't need this first trick with conversion to json but you would need to slightly adjust yq filter. I also assume you have kubectl installed and of course xargs which should be available by default on all linux machines.